# how to find the exact system table name to disable recaptcha module in Drupal？ help needed

Tags: recaptcha, drupal-8, drupal-modules, system-tables

how to find the exact system table name to disable recaptcha module in Drupal？  my Drupal version is 8.5.5

I have followed the Drupal official doc and run command:
UPDATE system SET status = 0 WHERE name = "recaptcha"; 
but Seeing an error “ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'drupal.system' doesn't exist,  So wondering if I use the right table name? Thank you very much.

Comment: When i ran the following command to show table , i can not find the table named "system" of 131 rows in set:

So wondering if I use the right table name? how to find the exact system table name to disable captcha module in Drupal ？ my Drupal version is 8.5.5 Thank you very much.

when i ran command to show database, it looks like :
| information_schema |
| drupal

Comment: when i ran command to show database, it looks like :
| information_schema |
| drupal |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set